# Webpack can't load fonts (ttf)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fonts, font-face, webpack-3

Currently I have 3 fonts that I want to add to my React project:*a, a light, a bold*. 

My file structure:

```
/src
├── /fonts/
│   ├── /A.ttf
│   ├── /A-light.ttf
│   └── /A-bold.ttf
│  
├── /styles/
│   ├── /base/
│   │   └── /__base.scss
│   └── styles.scss
│ 
├── app.jsx
└── webpack.config.js
```

_base.scss:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "A";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../../fonts/A.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "A";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url("../../fonts/A-bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "A";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("../../fonts/A-light.ttf") format("truetype");
}
body {
  font-family: A, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

_base.scss is imported by styles.scss and styles.scss is imported in app.jsx.
My webpack config looks like this:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('dotenv').config({path: '.env.development'});
}

module.exports = env => {
  const isProduction = env === 'production';
  const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

  return {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.jsx'],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: CSSExtract.extract({
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true
                }
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true
                }
              }
            ]
          })
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'url-loader'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      CSSExtract,
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.API_AUTH_TOKEN': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_AUTH_TOKEN),
        'process.env.API_EMAIL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_EMAIL),
        'process.env.API_PASSWORD': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_PASSWORD)
      }),
      new StyleLintPlugin({})
    ],
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      overlay: {
        warnings: true,
        errors: true
      },
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    }
  };
};
```

However Webpack fails to compile.

Error:

> ./src/styles/styles.scss
>       Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../fonts/A.ttf'

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I realize this was a long time ago, but shouldn't your src statement `src: url("../../fonts/A.ttf")` have an extra `../` to find the fonts directory?

Comment: Not a single resource on the entire internet that shows a full, simple working example. Incredible.

Answer (score 15):

Using 'ttf-loader' from npm worked perfectly for me.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttf-loader

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.ttf$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'ttf-loader',
          options: {
            name: './font/[hash].[ext]',
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As of webpack 5 you can use built-in asset modules instead. From the official Webpack guide [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/), add this to `module.rules` to load .ttf files:

```
{
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

Comment: nothing worked for me except this answer ...

Answer (score 10):

Re Webpack 5: In case this is helpful to anyone else, here is a solution to what seems to be a common issue experienced when loading truetype fonts using Webpack 5. It's actually a CSS issue.

In the Webpack 5 Asset Management section of the docs, under the heading "Loading Fonts", the style.css file has the following example @font-face declaration:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('./my-font.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./my-font.woff') format('woff');
}
```

In order for this declaration to work with other font types, such as truetype or opentype fonts, the `format` needs to be specified correctly. Any of the following `format` types are valid:

"woff", "woff2", "truetype", "opentype", "embedded-opentype", "svg".

If you set the `format` type to "ttf" or "otf", for example, the font will not be imported. The `format` type is there to tell the browser the font's format but is not compulsory, so, if you leave it out, your font should still load correctly.

Assuming you have set up the path to your font correctly, this example should work as expected:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont';
   src: url('./my-font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

This should also work:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFont';
   src: url('./my-font.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Webpack requires a font loader to load font files present in your project. you are using a file loader to load fonts.
Change

```
{
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
      name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
 }
```

to

```
 {
      test: /\.ttf$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'ttf-loader',
          options: {
            name: './font/[hash].[ext]',
          },
        },
      ]
  }
```

by installing a font loader in your project like
[TTF Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttf-loader) from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that didn't help.
Also I've changed "'./font/[hash].[ext]'" to "name: './fonts/[hash].[ext]'".

Comment: You should import ttfs in your code!

    import someFontFamily from 'name-of-font.ttf';

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the font path with `~`, to tell Webpack that this is not a relative import
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports